# Autoencoder Incorrect Output/Predict - Model Built and Trained. *Please Assist*

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

### Background

Let me preface, I am new to python and machine learning.
I have been tasked with creating an autoencoder to reduce dimensionality on a made-up dataset (proof of concept).

I am working in google colab. I also have the anaconda version of py 3.x.x and use Jupiter notebook with it.

I have assembled the autoencoder and it trains and runs, however, when it is run and I get the outputs from my layers, I have columns of zeros in my layer outputs and sometimes my model outputs.

I believe having the columns of zeros is incorrect. I thought I resolved the issue by using .predict from my model layers then I receive non-zero values. However, my latent layer (feature extraction) shows values above 2 from the .predict. Which I also believe indicates a problem.

I have looked over the code dozens of times, but I see no issue.

As a note my weights are not tied.

### Questions

1. Is having a column of zeros in decoder/encoder layers or latent layer an immediate sign of an issue?
2. Should I be looking at the outputs or the .predictions for feature extraction?
3. Where do I have an issue or is it working correctly?

Data Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cGOrdm7IvnpjBi8Zy0nVJ9m4gckF_TzNRlL3ronnzuA/edit?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import constant
import datetime, os
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
import re

%matplotlib inline
%reload_ext tensorboard

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 8


#Setup Random Seed
RANDOM_SEED = 13

df = pd.read_csv("autoencoder_ts1_nolabel_Reworked.csv")
X = df.iloc[:, :8].values
y = df.iloc[:, :8].values

# Copy initial "df" data frame to "data" data frame.
data = df

# Split data 80% Training / 20% Testing -> picked at random using RANDOM_SEED value from the Pre-amble.
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

#Large range of values from each variable (column) require a scaled version of the dataset for loss to converge.
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Confirm Intended Train Shape (5034 * .80) = 4027 Rows
X_train.shape

# Determine the Number of items in the 
# Shape: [7] -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8
#number of neurons in each hidden layer. progression above shows desired # of neurons.
input_size = 8
hidden_size = 4 
code_size = 2 

#Model declaration using Sequential and Dense Layers
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

ip = autoencoder.add(Dense(input_size, input_shape = (8,), activation = 'relu',name = 'input_layer')) #Input - Dense layer with input shape
encode = autoencoder.add(Dense(hidden_size,activation ='relu', name = 'encode_layer')) # Encoder - Dense layer from 8 neurons to 4
code = autoencoder.add(Dense(code_size, activation = 'relu', name = 'code_layer')) # Latent/code layer reducing neurons from 4 to 2
decode = autoencoder.add(Dense(hidden_size, activation = 'relu', name = 'decode_layer')) # Decode layer - expanding from 2 to 4 neurons
op =autoencoder.add(Dense(input_size,activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'output_layer')) # Ouput layer - expands from 4 to 8 neurons. Should recreate input

#Sub-models - Used to capture features/outputs from each layer in the autoencoder
input_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('input_layer').output)
input_layer_output = input_layer_model(X_test)

encode_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('encode_layer').output)
encode_output = encode_layer_model(X_test)

code_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('code_layer').output)
code_output = code_layer_model(X_test)

decode_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('decode_layer').output)
decode_output = decode_layer_model(X_test)

output_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input,outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('output_layer').output)
output_layer_output = output_layer_model(X_test)

# The number of times to cycle through the data.
epoch = 128

# The number of records (samples) to group together 
batch_size = 256

# Compile Neural Network Model
#  - optimizer: method for changing attributes to minimize loss
#  - loss: how the model's performance will be judged
#  - metrics: how the loss will be judged
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)

#Train the model
autoencoder.fit(x=X_train,y=X_train,epochs=epoch, shuffle = True, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

autoencoder.summary()

Weights = autoencoder.get_weights()

encode_output_prediction = encode_layer_model.predict(X_test)
df_encode_output_prediction = pd.DataFrame(encode_output_prediction)

code_layer_output = code_layer_model.predict(X_test)
df_code_layer_output = pd.DataFrame(code_layer_output)

decode_output_prediction = decode_layer_model.predict(X_test)
df_decode_output_prediction = pd.DataFrame(decode_output_prediction)

output_prediction = autoencoder.predict(X_test)
df_output_prediction = pd.DataFrame(output_prediction)

df_X_TEST = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
output_layer_model.predict(X_test)


plot_model(autoencoder, to_file='autoencoder_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

[image: Features from .predict function (where other layers are non-zero)]
[image: Code output - NOT .Predict]
[image: Encoder layer output (not .predict - shows column of zeros)]

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing it, but did you normalize/scale the data before feeding it into the model?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I used a minmax scalar on the dataset as each column has significantly different magnitudes of values.